# Custom placemarks directly on maps.google.com for my map

Tags: google-maps

I made a custom map with a couple of placemarks on it. I have copied html code and pasted it into my web page. Everything works fine. The map and placemarks are displayed correctly.

And when I press the bottom left corner button "Click to see this area on Google Maps" I can see my map directly on maps.google.com but the placemarks disappear.

Is it possible to show the placemarks on my map right on the maps.google.com? or can I manage placemarks for my custom map directly on maps.google.com using API?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to what you are after is MyMaps.  My maps lets you create map content ( or import KML, KMZ, or GeoRSS files), on maps.google.com.  I think you can programaticaly create maps via the [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata).

I am not sure what your requirement is, but if your content is static you could create a [MyMap](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=en&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=109115301202341389527.00046e1cbfbb8b2595d31) up front and then load that url rather than maps.google.com.

Comment: I haven't used the Maps Data API, but if I get a chance, I'll try it out and let you know how I go.

Comment: Hrm ... looks like this is exactly what you need (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingAccount).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of what i need -)

We send request to maps.google.com to show some area (sending latitude, longtitude, zoom) and then we specify the placemarks we want, not by hand (using MyMaps) but using API. And we need to do it directly on the maps.google.com, not on my own site or home page with embeded or even programm builded map.

Thanks to Cannonade. The links you've shared helps me a lot -)

Comment: You can edit your original question to add more information, rather than adding a new answer.